# Any idea to write compress text file to hdfs by Flink BucketingSink with fault tolerant?

Tags: apache-flink

Recently we are doing a job to write compressed(gzip) text file to hdfs by BucketingSink of Apache Flink. However the problem is that whenever a failure occurs, it generate a valid-length file(for hadoop < 2.7) or truncate the file(for hadoop >=2.7). However gzip is a binary format and truncating does not simplely work. Any good ideas can help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: A truncated file sounds like a bug - have you posted this to the Flink user mailing list?

Comment: It is not a bug I think. BucketingSink only records filleValidLength as state. However truncating a compressed format to validlength will corrupt the file. So I am seeking an approach to handle this issue.